How would the following changes affect this monster's CR?
I'm trying to adapt the Alzabo, a monster featured in Gene Wolf's New Sun novels to D&D. To do this I got the idea of starting with the Otyugh and adapting it from there. The creature's size and type (large aberration) remain the same as do its natural armor, senses and primary stats (with one conditional exception- see below) with the following changes:
The creature's hide gets a coat of red fur (this would be cosmetic, wouldn't affect its stats),
Remove the three tentacles (obviously this would affect its stats),
Probably give the creature claws and a fourth leg (forgot otyughs were tripedal),
This last one is the tricky part, and I'm not entirely sure it can be worked for D&D-
Knowledge/memory absorption: When the monster eats a creature with a higher intelligence than its own that isn't an undead, elemental or construct (as for why it would, let's just assume the monster mistook them for something edible and move on), it gains that higher intelligence for the next eight hours. During those eight hours the Alzabo has the knowledge and memories of the creature it consumed, can speak any languages the creature knew (with the creature's voice), can cast any spell the creature knew that only had vocal components and can use any psionic talents the creature knew. Once those eight hours are up the Alzabo's Int returns to normal and any new knowledge, powers or magic are lost. Should the Alzabo consume another creature of even higher intelligence before the eight hours expire it gains that creature's higher Int however the time period does not increase (for example, an Alzabo that devoured a particularly apt wizard five hours after consuming an earlier humanoid of slightly less intelligence would still revert to its normal intelligence three hours later). EDIT: per a point mentioned in Shivers' answer, the Alzabo does not gain knowledge of an eaten corpse the Alzabo itself didn't kill, so munching on the corpse of an archmage who croaked of old age a week prior would give it no benefit.
With all these changes (and assuming the last one can even be done at all), what would be the most appropriate Challenge Rating for this new monster?

Show your working please; what CR have you come up with and how?

Are you planning for th creature to have eaten before they meet the party? Or expecting them to eat a party member?

@SeriousBri- I'm trying to make a way for an ability the monster had in the source material to fit in D&D mechanics.

You don't plan the CR for the general monster, you plan it for the version the party are going to meet
What I mean by this is that an Alzabo that has just eaten an archmage is so vastly different to one that hasn't that they may as well be different creatures, so it is better to treat them as such.
Work out how the party are going to meet the creature, decide what CR you want the encounter to be, and have them eat something appropriate just before (or even as) the party encounter them.
If you are looking for a general CR then I am afraid it just won't work the way you want it to.
How I would do it
I would narrow down the range of powers they can get from eating a corpse.
Instead of getting the spells from the creature they would get spells from a set list which depends on the INT they get from the corpse. This way you can fully control the power and keep it within certain limits.
I would build the monster in such a way that at default INT it might be CR5, then design the spell lists so that each 2 points of additional INT adds +1 CR (Or whatever feels better to you) and essentially treat it like being in a lair in the way it interacts with CR.

Correct. There is no possible way to put one single CR on this creature that covers both a starving Alzabo and one that just ate Elminster.

This is the right answer. +1

CR calculations can't account for that kind of ability.
CR is mostly about offense and defense.
The utility and strength of absorbing the intelligence and other aspects of a dead creature depends entirely on what dead creatures it's able to eat. Calculating a challenge rating is primary based on raw combat potential: calculate a defensive CR based on HP/AC, calculate an office CR based on DPR, attack, and DCs, then average those scores for the final CR, with an important caveat:

Creating a monster isn't just a number-crunching exercise. The guidelines in this chapter can help you create monsters, but the only way to know whether a monster is fun is to playtest it. After seeing your monster in action, you might want to adjust the challenge rating up or down based on your experiences.

There are some characteristics that can be boiled down to defense or offense in a mostly-deterministic way, such as resistances and immunities, which are treated as HP scalars if they're likely to come up. The issue is that the power of knowledge absorption is extremely wide and thus can't factor into a fixed CR.
Memory absorption can range from irrelevant to game-breaking.
The party happens upon an alzabo inhabiting a broken-down barn on an abandoned farm. After briefly trying to parley, it becomes evident that peace is out of the question and everyone rolls initiative. On its turn, the alzabo does one of the following:

Bites and makes two claw attacks because it's just been eating wild game and thus memory absorption has had no effect.
Casts Zephyr Strike and sprints past the front line to attack the squishy wizard because it just finished eating a ranger who had been investigating missing wildlife in the area.
Opens with Power Word: Kill on the cleric because it managed to break into the university graveyard and ate the corpse of the headmaster who just died.

There's simply too much variability in what the ability does. Since it can range from "does not modify game statistics at all" to "gains abilities far beyond its normal CR," there's no single number that's going to cover it. Spellcasting itself gets a specific callout that its impact on CR can be variable, and you're adding variable spellcasting from the get go:

The impact that the Innate Spellcasting and Spellcasting special traits have on a monster's challenge rating depends on the spells that the monster can cast. Spells that deal more damage than the monster's normal attack routine and spells that increase the monster's AC or hit points need to be accounted for when determining the monster's final challenge rating.

Plan around it irrespective of CR.
If you're not publishing the stat block, the CR doesn't really matter. While there's a deterministic way to calculate a CR, there are myriad cases where the CR doesn't, in itself, guarantee a balanced fight. The player party and the circumstances of the fight can have a massive effect on the potency of foes, addressed in questions and answers like this one which goes into how ghouls can be trivial or brutal.
Since you need to decide if a monster is a fun/fair fight for the party dependent on circumstances, you have the circumstances for knowledge absorption. Effectively, my advice here is to decide what abilities the alzabo would have for the fight and decide if that's balanced for the party. You could calculate a CR based on those additional abilities, but at that point you're basically just doing it as an exercise.

If you're not publishing the stat block, the CR doesn't really matter. Except for the fact that you need to know how much XP to award... unless you are using a variant.

There's a couple of creatures like this already
I concur with the other answers in saying that it's very difficult to assess the CR of such an ability and I think you need to handle this on a case by case basis.
That said, I know of at least two creatures in the monster manual which have abilities similar to this that may be worth reviewing:

Elder Oblex (CR10): This creature has the ability to drain memories from creatures it attacks (doesn't need to kill them either). Creatures who have their memories drained allow the Elder Oblex to learn all of its languages as well as skill proficiencies and also take a scaling penalty to most d20 rolls.
Fraz-Urb'luu (CR24 in lair): This is a full-blown demon lord and has a devastating lair action which allows it to create a simulacrum of a humanoid in its lair which lasts until Initiative 20 on the next round.

I used both of these monsters in a high level game a few years ago and the Elder Oblex's abilities were mostly annoying to the players. In general, you don't expect an ooze to suddenly be able to reliably make Acrobatics checks, but that happens when the Ranger gets their memories drained.
Conversely, Fraz-Urb'luu's simulacrum ability can be devastating to the players, because it has the ability to duplicate the party's Cleric and regularly cast spells like Mass Heal or their Wizard and cast Prismatic Wall (could've been even worse if the simulacrum had material components). The party definitely felt frustrated by this enemy.
I will say that with the Elder Oblex, the ability to gain skill proficiencies didn't really make the fight harder. The bulk of the contribution to its CR was the scaling penalty it imposed.
For Fraz-Urb'luu, I will say that the monster's CR23 is probably high for how dangerous it is in a direct fight. But I will also say that the standard rule of thumb to just add 1 to the CR for a monster in it's lair wildly underestimates how dangerous the simulacrum lair action is. When we talk about the issues of linear Fighters and quadratic Wizards, I can say that that Fraz-Urb'luu very rarely saw a compelling reason to use the simulacrum ability on a martial character (one time he duplicated the Monk to deliver a litany of Stunning Strikes). In a somewhat ironic fashion, the odds to defeat Fraz-Urb'luu in his lair via combat is actually more likely to succeed with a weaker party (though that party still needs to get through a myriad of illusions and distractions).

It depends on what you want it to be.
First note that the Otyugh has a CR of 5. If you want to keep it that way it'll be relatively simple.
First, replace the tentacle attacks with claw attacks. For this, you could easily substitute a troll's (also a CR 5 monster) claw attack, which, adjusted for strength would be a +6 to hit and 2d6+3 damage. It'll get 2 of these.
Second, replace the bite attack with your modified version of a swallow ability, many existing creatures have this, such as the Giant Toad. Depending on the damage and the bonuses associated with this attack, it could raise or lower the CR of the monster. However, the ability to copy the swallowed creatures spells is interesting, but probably just flavor text, as it probably wouldn't be relevant unless your creature had eaten a powerful spellcaster within 8 hours of fighting your party. However, as such a low CR monster, would eating a high level caster be likely, probably not.

I imagined the final result probably having a higher CR than 5, from what you've said the  knowledge absorption power might have to be tweaked to be more useful/dangerous- I'd hate for it to be just flavor text.
